# Angular: wait for Observable inside a function before returning result

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need help with the following function:

```
  getUser(uuid: string): Observable<WowUserDataModel> {
    let user: WowUserDataModel = {
      login: null,
      userUuid: uuid,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      displayName: null,
      email: null,
      authorities: null
    };

    return this.http.get(WowUrlProvider.gateway.wowUserAuthorities.replace('{userUuid}', uuid.toUpperCase())).pipe(
      map((authorities) =>
        user.authorities = authorities,
      )
    );
  }
```

**What I need:** to wait for the this.http.api call (which returns Observable) to complete, assign the result to user.authorities, and only then return Observable of the entire user object (always a single user)

**What is happening now:** the function returns just authorities property, not the whole user object

Can this be achieved without changing the return type of the function?

Comment: Try instead of `(authorities) =>user.authorities = authorities` to use `(authorities) =>
{...user, authorities}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
getUser(uuid: string): Observable<WowUserDataModel> {
  // ...
    return this.http.get(WowUrlProvider.gateway.wowUserAuthorities.replace('{userUuid}', uuid.toUpperCase())).pipe(
      map((authorities) => {
       user.authorities = authorities;
       return user;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Geee, so simple! I was trying to return of(user) this whole time. Thank you, you saved my day!

Comment: @PaulJK If your code was trying to return `of(user)`, why didn't you mention that in your question? Please be more specific in what you have tried.

Comment: It's not the code, it's me. I simply assumed that user isn't an observable without checking it, and I was trying to make it an observable manually and getting errors. Feeling real dumb right now.

Comment: @PaulJK don't worry, it takes practice to know really well rxjs operators, just keep practicing, also, if you use `map` as shown in your example, whatever you send inside of it, is an observable, no need of returning `of(...)` unless you want a double observable...